# Expo FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync doesn't act like a Promise

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise, expo

I'm using the function Expo.writeAsStringAsync()
(docs: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/#filesystemwriteasstringasyncfileuri-contents-options).
I noticed that it needs different times with different size files (as expected), but there is no way to know when it has finished, because it returns nothing. So, if I have to access the file just after writing it, I could find it empty, because maybe it's still writing.

Is there any way to receive an answer when it has completed? like a normal promise-then-catch?

P.S.: I've tried to promisify it, but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that the API docs are misleading because they don't specify the return type.

In fact that API call is defined as `async` function (see [source-code](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/400de72306a91c738c6ad0aad238b45b51a1a92a/packages/expo-file-system/src/FileSystem.ts#L99-L108)):

```
export async function writeAsStringAsync(
  fileUri: string,
  contents: string,
  options: WritingOptions = {}
): Promise<void> {
  // ...
}
```

Every `async` function returns a Promise (you can see in TypeScript signature above it says `Promise<void>`).

This means you can use the returned Promise and `await` for it or use `.then()` to wait for the moment of filesystem call to complete.

```
await Expo.writeAsStringAsync(fileUri, contents, options);
// do something when write is finished 
// you can catch errors with try/catch clause
```

or

```
Expo.writeAsStringAsync(fileUri, contents, options).then(
  () => { /* do something when write is finished */ }
).catch(err => { /* handle errors */ }
```